# Geocaching - XY coordinates

Tags: data, geocaching, coordinates

I was wondering what is the easiest way to get XY geocaching coordinates (by a particular Area of Interest (AOI)) data in a spread sheet format that I could covert to a GIS layer?  On the [Geocaching.com](http://www.geocaching.com/) website you can search by different AOI, but I do not see a way to mass export XY coordinates.

Comment: There is an API coming soon - http://feedback.geocaching.com/forums/75775-geocaching-com/suggestions/1050915-api-for-3rd-party-applications currently you cannot scrape data without breaking terms and conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have FME Desktop, it's possible to extract some informations with API and convert the information to SHAPEFILE or another GIS file.

Or if you copy some geocaching data with xy in Excel, you can generate a shapefile with ArcGis.

Comment: I'm not familiar with FME Desktop, how can you grab many XY data values from a API using FME?

Comment: See http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist66/